# C# Console split number to digit and do math

Tags: c#, console, numbers

I have a user input, lets say 3 digit number.  I want to split the numbers and add them or multiply - it doesn't matter.

This is what I tried to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter a number: ");
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string temp = userInput.ToString();
int x = 0;
foreach(char c in temp)
{
    x += c;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm not allowed to use `%`

Any suggestion?!

Comment: What is the exact input you give in the ReadLine? An example could let us better understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Console.ReadLine() was already a string why are you converting to an Int then back to a string?

Comment: You are not allowed to use % where??
Also, you get a string from user (console.ReadLine()), convert it to an integer and then converting the integer back to a string (the same string user inserted): avoid this roundtrip

Comment: `I want to split the numbers and add them or multiply - it doesnt matter.` which one is it...?

Comment: If you want to calculate sum of digits of a number, you can read characters of the string and use them.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("enter a number: ");` shouldn't that be 
`Console.WriteLine("enter any 3 digit number: ");`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate sum of digits of a number, you can read characters of the string and convert them to numbers and then use them:

```
string number = Console.ReadLine();
var sum = number.ToArray().Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

---

Also as an option without using `Linq`:

```
string number = Console.ReadLine();
int sum = 0;
foreach (char c in number)
{
    sum += int.Parse(c.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: From the looks of the question it looks like this may be a beginners class. I doubt they would be at LINQ already. Love the answer but just a hunch.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey Another option added for beginners. Hope you find it useful for beginners :)

Comment: this answer only works partially `For SUM()` what about for `Multiplication`..?

Comment: @MethodMan I added another option (using foreach) that can be used for multiplication.